# How to restore the privileges of the user postgres in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Someone logged in my *PostgreSQL* as the user `postgres`, because a lack of security in my configuration files. What he did is to create a lot of superusers, and then, he revoked `SUPERUSER` privilege from `postgres`.

I've corrected the configuration files to avoid more problems, but now the harm is done and I can only log in as `postgres`, who is no more a superuser.

I would like to grant `SUPERUSER` privileges again to `postgres` user, but of course as I can't log in as a superuser I can't do it. Which is the best way to achieve this? I prefer to avoid reinstalling `postgresql`, is there other way?

I've also glanced the *PostgreSQL* log and I've seen the moment when the users were created, and their passwords, but these ones are encrypted through MD5 and I'm not able to desencrypt them.

What would you do in this case? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you edit your `pg_hba.conf` to allow login as one of the other superusers, then you can login as one of those and then `alter role postgres superuser`.

Comment: Do you mean to modify the line `local : all : all : md5` and wrtite `local : all : all : trust`, restart PostgreSQL service and log in as a superuser whose password I don't know, don't you?

Comment: It's more secure to add a special line for one account, like `local all <user> trust`. Or change to `trust` to `peer` if you're able to add an OS user with the same name.

Comment: That was it! Thank you @Colin 't Hart you've saved my day :)